# Bootstrap 3: Container Div Overlapping

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I am designing a frontend with Bootstrap 3.3.7 and using Flatly theme.

I am running into an issue which I think should have trivial solution.

I want a container split into 70-30 ratio and I am trying this HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   <custom-data-table/>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
   <label for="searchQ">Search</label>
   <input
    required
    minlength="1"
    id="searchQ"
    ngModel name="searchQ"
    type="text"
    #searchQ="ngModel"
    (change)="log(searchQ)"/>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

With this style, I run into Overlapping Divs no matter how wide I make my screen.

I want a screen shared by these 2 DIVs in 70:30 ratio without overlapping.

Any suggestion/ideas are appreciated!

This is the overlapping problem:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use one single column and divide it using your own custom logic:

```css
.myThing {
  display:flex;
}
.myThing .firstColumn {
  flex: 0 0 70%;
}
.myThing .second {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 myThing">
    <div class="firstColumn"></div>
    <div class="secondColumn"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I used flex here but you can use floating `blocks`, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, could you please guide me to a documentation where I can learn more about such tricks?

Comment: [Over here](https://www.w3.org/standards/techs/css#w3c_all). But they're not tricks. They're standards. By comparison, Bootstrap is a trick. W3C should be your bible. If you find it too technical, use MDN.